# C# -Do I have to add out parameter to parameters collection

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, out

I have a stored procedure that has an OUT parameter of type SYS_REFCUROR. From C# before executing the procedure I add all the parameters except for that OUT parameter. But when I execute the procedure I get "wrong number or types of arguments " error. My question is if I'm not going to assign any value to that parameter why do I have to add it to my parameters collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add out the parameter because after execution of the stored procedure, the value of out parameter of sql is stored in this out parameter you supplied in your code, which you can use later on in your further execution.

**If you want to omit passing out the parameter, then assign a default value to the output parameter, that will resolve your issue.**

**For example :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTest
   @Data1 int
   ,@Data3 int = null output
```

If you do as above, then you don't need to pass the output parameter by code, and it will hide the error you are getting.

Comment: We cannot add default value to OUT and IN OUT parameters in Oracle. Don't know about SQL Server.

Comment: @MikeJM - with sql server you can do that but oracle i have not idea ..if its not than you need to add out prameter from you code no option left

Comment: But wait a minute. What if I do not assign any value to my OUT parameter in the procedure? This might be the case because my OUT parameter is a SYS_REFCURSOR. And I only open that cursor for some select statement if my V_TYPE parameter is 0, otherwise I do Insert, Update or Delete upon the value of the V_TYPE, so I don't assign any value to that OUT parameter.

Comment: @MikeJM - if you are not assigning value to out parameter just assing defult value or null to it but as i know you cannt ommit passing of out prameter..